# Electron in an accelerating frame - a paradox

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

Suppose I am at point $a$ and I have an electron at rest at point $b$ some $r$ distance away. Say that I suddenly start spinning clockwise about my point $a$ at some constant angular velocity $\omega$. Now, if I consider I am at rest, then it is the electron which would be revolving around me in anticlockwise direction. But then, if I see the electron accelerating (i.e., going in a circle around me), I must also see it radiating, lose its energy and then fall in a spiral towards me. This contradicts the assumption that the electron is at rest and hence shouldn't really radiate energy. How do we resolve this paradox?

Answer (score 2):

The Maxwell equations do not remain invariant in form when changing to a rotating coordinate system and therefore predictions made from them, like the Larmor radiation formula, cannot be held to be true anymore.

While that sentence is sufficient to answer your question, if you want to dive deeper, here are some quick resources:

http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/rotatingEM.pdf

http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9801194

http://piers.org/piers2k4Pisa/session_07/07_01.pdf